# IntelliJ stucks at loading page

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ stuck at loading page. It cannot open. What should I do?

My default java version is JDK 10. I downloaded JDK 9 and changed to jdk9. Then when i open Intellij, it stuck at loading page. I am using MAC Pro. I have reinstalled the app but it still does not work. help

[image]

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002876439/comments/360000352499

Answer (score 0):

you should check the log file. It's located in:

```
~/Library/Logs/IdeaIC<VERSION>
```

note: you must replace <VERSION> with your version number.